# MMO Game health and Armour Method

Tags: java

I am making a MMO game on Java (net bean) and I want the player to have both Armour and health. But I don't know how to set it so that the enemy's damage with first take away the Armour and the remaining damage with be subtracted by the health.

```
 int Armour = 100;
 int Health = 100;
 int Damage = 101;

 while (Armour > 0){
 Armour -= Damage;
 }
 if (Armour < 0){
 Health += Armour;
 }

 System.out.println(Armour);
 System.out.println(Health);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
int armour = 100;
int health = 100;
int damage = 101;

if (damage <= armour) {
  armour -= damage;
} else {
  health -= (damage - armour);
  armour = 0;
}

System.out.println(armour);
System.out.println(health);
```

The snippet above distinguished between two cases:

1. If the damage is smaller than the armour, the armour gets affected with the damage, and the health is unchanged.
2. Otherwise, the damage that is not absorbed by the armour is subtracted from the health, and the armour is set to zero.

Note that:

- The convention for Java variable names is `lowerCamelCase`, i.e. they should start with a lowercase letter.
- There's still an edge case where the health could go below zero. Depending on your requirements this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Upvoted for the solution and addition comment on Java coding standard